# Xpath: How to select text between two <br/> nodes in HTML

Tags: html, xpath

Is it possible to get text between two 
 nodes in html. Code look like:

```
<div @class='article'>
    <br/>
    <br/> Art. 25a, Sec. 1 WpHG 
    <br/> 
    <br/> thereof held indirectly: 0.00% (equals 0 voting rights) 
    <br/> 
    <br/> Art. 25 WpHG: 0.00% (equals 0 voting rights) 
    <br/> 
    <br/> 0.00% (equals 0 voting rights) 
    <br/> 
    <br/> Art. 21, 22 WpHG 
    <br/> 
    <br/> 8. ISIN continous 
    <br/>
</div>
```

I want to have xpath which will select text 8. ISIN...

Can somebody help to write xpath? Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Could be used if the text always is placed second:

```
//div[@class='article']/text()[2]
```

Comment: But in case if we do not know after which <br/> is this text. Can we somehow write with text? Contains(text(), 'text2') or smth like else?

Comment: yes you can say: //div[@class='article']/text()[contains(text(), 'text2')], assuming you know what the text is

Comment: It does not make much sense to search for a string you already know. @user4737457 What exactly would you like to find? Which structures are stable in the document and known, and what is not? In your sample document, `text3` is _also_ between two `br` elements.

Comment: @user4737457 Never post essential information (least of all code) in a comment, please **edit your question** instead.